# passing between windows and writing

Tags: javascript

I have written a script that opens a pop up window , searches for a user , when finds 
the user the search window closes and then the script shows the new user in the parent window.

Basically I tried all of the script separately but I have problems when I pass between windows. The code ahead does not pass the found user, but passes one example user just for meantime to debug the code.

Here is the script file: ( I will explain it later )

```
var orgWindow        
var searchWindow

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".add_participants").on("click", function() {
    var orgWindow = window.self          
var searchWindow = window.open("http://localhost:3000/users/search", "_blank",
        "left=200, top=100, height=300, width=300, menubar=yes");
  });
});         

function printUser(){
  var a  = orgWindow.document.createElement("a");
  a.setAttribute("href","/users/show");
  a.setAttribute("id","3");

  var aText = orgWindow.document.createTextNode("elad bezalel");
  var img = orgWindow.document.createElement("img");
  img.setAttribute("alt","El4");
  img.setAttribute("src","/uploads/user/image/3/el4.jpg");
  img.setAttribute("height","150");
  img.setAttribute("width","150");

  myDiv = orgWindow.document.getElementById("par");

  a.appendChild(img);

  var brk = orgWindow.document.createElement("br");
  a.appendChild(brk);
  a.appendChild(aText);

  myDiv.appendChild(a);
}

function add_user(){
  user_id = $("#button").data("user_id");
  window.close(searchWindow);
  window.blur(searchWindow);
  window.focus(orgWindow);
  orgWindow.document.write(printUser());
  orgWindow.close();
}
```

I am using jQuery. when I click a button the search window open. Then I find a user in the search window and click on another button (add user) and then the search window closes and the parent window gets focused. Now I tried to implement the user image and name, but somehow it doesn't work.

How should I repair my script?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you have declared `orgWindow` and `searchWindow` as variables in two different scopes, the global scope *(the two var usages at the top)* and local to the click handler. This *could* be part of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the two separate window contexts are getting intermingled.

In the main page `add_user` function:

```
function add_user(user_id){
  window.close(searchWindow);
  window.blur(searchWindow);
  window.focus(orgWindow);
  orgWindow.document.write(printUser());
  orgWindow.close();
}
```

And in the popup:

```
$("#button").click($(window.opener).add_user($(this).data("user_id")));
```